# Value of type 'String' does not conform to 'Any' in coercion

Tags: json, swift4

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]
let jsonString = jsonResult.map { 
    return ($0.key, "\($0.value)" == "<null>" || "\($0.value)" == "nil" ? "null" : "\($0.value)")
}
httpPOST(to: "\(postURL)/process/", withData: [("user" , userID), ("password", password)] + jsonString) {
    reply in
    Log.debug("Made request with \(jsonResult["sessionID"] as Optional) replyed \(reply as Optional)" as Any)
}
```

I'm having trouble with the Log.debug() line. I keep getting 'Value of type 'String' does not conform to 'Any' in coercion'. I'm not sure how to format this into a better line.

Comment: remove `as Any` from `Log'

Answer (score 0):

Do youself a favor and stop dumping complex expressions inside \()

do

```
let sid = jsonResult["sessionID"] as whatever
```

then

```
Log.debug("Made request with \(sid)...
```

I've had this 'String' does not conform to 'Any' in a different
situation than yours

and having a dumber verbose version allowed to see my equivalent of your session id for what (type) it was.

I've got a different and more amicable error from swift compiler once I stopped putting everything and the kitchen think into that smart looking string (extrapolation).

Assume swift compiler is dumb: it really is dumber than it appears, so, see above.